# Simplify NETSTAT monitoring output

Tags: awk, monitoring, netstat, watch, simplification

I'm monitoring suspicious incoming connections using

```bash
sudo watch -n 30 "netstat -antp"
```

which provides more information than I need, so based on the answer I found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/398234/netstat-continuous-refresh-watch-changes-the-output?newreg=97bb24bf924c42e1ade33b96f7614d82),
I've tried to simplify the output by displaying only the PID/program name columns but when I type the following command

```bash
sudo watch -n 30 "netstat -antp | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n"
```

I get the following output:

```
1                 <------ *1
1 1067/containerd
1 1662/dnsmasq
1 5131/whatsdesk
1 911/systemd-resolve
1 Remoto          <------ *2
2 1059/cupsd
2 1/init
2 2203/core
6 4806/chrome
```

Some of the outputs are not displayed, like *1 while others don't show the PID/program name but "Remote (remote)" instead like *2. As I'm doing this for security purposes, I'm highly interested in processes started remotely, so, why does this happen when the full output provides all the required information? And more importantly, how do I change my command to get the complete simplified output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps use Wireshark instead for what you wish to do.

Comment: What do these funny connections look like in the unprocessed original output?

Comment: Probably I would be able to solve it using wireshark, but the idea is to have a small window console in my working space all the time, that's why I'm using netstat. 

The regular output looks like this:

https://ibb.co/kX9Lwpw